# Wicket 9: user forced to log in again when accessing a certain page for first time after deployment

Tags: java, rendering, wicket

I am upgrading a legacy application from Wicket 1.5 to 9.0, and have noticed a strange behaviour in one particular situation. A colleague who is upgrading a different application to Wicket 9 has also noticed exactly the same problem. We are using Windows 10 Enterprise, JDK 11.0.7, NetBeans 11.3 and Payara 5.201.

**About the error**

This problem does not occur in every browser.

- It does **not** happen in Firefox (92.0.1(64-bit))
- It **does** happen in Chrome (Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit), updates disabled, managed by administrator)
- It **does** happen in Edge (Version 94.0.992.38 (Official build) (64-bit))

This error affects one single page in my colleague's application and two pages in mine. It occurs the first time that a user attempts to visit one of the affected pages. Even though the user is successfully logged in and their session has not expired, as soon as they click on the menu item that should lead them to the affected page, instead they are sent back to the login page.

If running our applications from within NetBeans on local host, this error occurs every time Chrome or Edge is opened. However, when the application is invoked using a fully qualified domain name, the error seems to be triggered just once after deployment. After the user re-logs in, the pages work properly again, and so far it seems they continue to work properly until the application is next redeployed. If we could rely on the error only happening once after deployment, we could find a work-round, but we worry that we cannot rely on it.

I added debug messages to the constructor and before/after render events of one of the affected pages. I discovered that at run time, debug messages from the constructor of the login page appear during the "on before render" event of the affected page.

**Unique features of the affected pages**

2021-10-22: I discovered that out of the hundreds of pages in my application, only the 2 affected pages import the following class and use the following statement:

```
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.WebClientInfo;

WebClientInfo info = (WebClientInfo) getSession().getClientInfo();
```

My colleague's application does not import this class, but the one affected page in that application is the only one, once again out of hundreds of classes, to contain a date selector.

**More about the affected pages**

The affected class to which I added debug messages displays an anonymised list of cases of diseases which need to be checked for medical research purposes.

The class has two child classes, the “Pending checks” list and the “In Progress checks” list, which call the parent class passing in a flag to say which type of cases to retrieve from the database. The child classes have no code of their own apart from a minimal constructor which immediately calls super, passing in a boolean "In Progress?" flag. However, the error **only** occurs in the "In Progress" version of the list.

The  “Checks Pending/In Progress” class routinely goes through the rendering process twice, as follows.

**Summary of steps when correctly rendered**

*First pass through*

- “Pending/In Progress” list: check authorisation (1)
- Identify self as “In Progress” (1)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: constructor (1)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on before render (1)

*Second pass through*

- “Pending/In Progress” list: check authorisation (2)
- Identify self as “In Progress” (2)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: constructor (2)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on before render (2)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on after render – “In Progress” list has now been correctly rendered.

**Summary of steps when incorrectly rendered**

*First pass through – same as when correctly rendered*

- “Pending/In Progress” list: check authorisation (1)
- Identify self as “In Progress” (1)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: constructor (1)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on before render (1)

*Second pass through*

- “Pending/In Progress” list: check authorisation (2)
- Identify self as “In Progress” (2)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: constructor (2)
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on before render (2)
- **Login page: Constructor (user is already logged in)**
- “Pending/In Progress” list: on after render – Login page has been rendered, not “In Progress”.

I have attempted to reproduce the error in a stripped-down version of the application, but unfortunately, once I remove complexity, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Both the affected pages in my application looked up Wicket class WebClientInfo to find out the physical size of the user’s screen, so that a popup window could be correctly sized.

When WebClientInfo is invoked for the first time after deployment, it seems to somehow create a new session in addition to the current session, and tries to render the current page twice, once for each of these two sessions. It seems that the new session has a null user, and that may be why the existing, logged-in user was forced back to the login page.

The solution I found was to look up the information I needed from WebClientInfo at the start of the constructor of the login page, and store it in a “My Session” object for later use. (I found it was important to put it in the constructor of the home/login page and not in the “on submit” event of the form.  I originally tried to put it in the “on submit”, and found this triggered a “Page intercept blocked” exception.)

The two pages that were previously rendered twice are now only rendered once, and are completely fine.

On the other hand, the home/login page is routinely rendered twice now. However, this does not really show to the user, apart from an annoying message which briefly appears on a plain white full-screen background, often for less than a second, but sometimes for about a whole second, then disappears as the login page is rendered. The message is:

> If you see this, it means both JavaScript and meta-refresh are not support by your browser configuration. Please click this link to continue to the original destination.

This is certainly less of an issue than the user being forced to log in twice, but is still not ideal. (The message is also incorrect because JavaScript **is** enabled on all my browsers.) So far I have found no way of suppressing it.

**29/10/2021. My colleague Xiaoming comments:**

I have got message "If you see this, it means that both JavaScript and meta-refresh are not support by your browser configuration. …" too.

It is from wicket-core-9.0.0.jar; org/apache/wicket/markup/html/pages/BrowserInfoPage.html

According to https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/pages/BrowserInfoPage.html

It says: "This page is being used by the default implementation of Session.getClientInfo(), which in turn uses a setting to determine whether this page should be redirected to (it does when it is true)."

Maybe you need to look at your code and adjust the way you record client info.

**THANK YOU, Xiaoming!**

After further investigation, the setting is the following line from the main application file:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
```

If this line is removed, the double-login error and annoying message both disappear. The flip side of this is that the popup window can no longer be tailored to the exact size of the user's device.

**08/11/2021**
For more information see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6929